# Jquery Validate success function not clearning valid labels on re-validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that uses JQuery Validate plugin to validate the data. For the username field (but not other fields on my form), I would like to display "Username available" next to the field if the username is available.

I have this almost working. The only thing that is problematic is when the user edits the username after they enter a valid value, the previous valid message is never removed, so next to the field it reads "Username available Username available", or "Username available Username available Username available" etc.

What changes would I need to make it remove the previous "Username available" message(s) when it re-validates this field?

My jquery success function is as follows:

```
$("form").validate({
        success: 
            function(label) {

                if (label.attr('for') == "username") {
                    var element = '#' + label.attr('for');
                    label.removeClass("error").addClass("valid").text("Username available");
                } else {
                    label.removeClass("error");
                }


        }
    });

    $("#regForm").validate();
});
```

Comment: There seems to be a couple of similar plugins. can you provide a link of somekind for the specific plugin?

Comment: Edward, please see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally figured this out myself. Looking at the source-code for the validate plugin, if you remove the "error" class from the valid label, the label will not be reused when it revalidates, instead it will create a new label.

So my way of working around that was to remove the .removeClass() from my success function and to modify my stylesheet's valid class to use !important to override items from the error class that were different.

New validate function:

```
$("form").validate({
    success: 
        function(label) {

            if (label.attr('for') == "username") {
                var element = '#' + label.attr('for');
                label.addClass("valid").text("Username available");
            } else {
                label.addClass("invisiblevalid"); //ie. hide
            }


    }
});

$("#regForm").validate();
```

});

modified stylesheet code:

```
label.error {
background: url('check.gif') no-repeat;
color: #FF0000;
}
label.valid {
background: url('check.gif') no-repeat !important; 
color: #339900 !important;
}
label.invisiblevalid {
display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you don't use `!important`, it's not recommended. Once you use it, you can't change it later without another !important. As the old saying goes, "if you're using !important, you're doing it wrong".

Comment: it is less than ideal to use !important, I would agree, if you have suggestions on how to improve the css to make it work without using the hack of !important to override precedence rules, I'm all ears

Comment: I have the same issue, the thing is that when a 'revalidation' happens (the user edits the contents of the field) the label then ends up with two classes, `error` and `success` like this: `<label for="username" class="error success">This field is required.</label>`. So what happens is that the label of the field that now has errors is taking the styles from ".valid" since `.valid` is using `!important`. Isn't there a way to have the plugin swap the `error` and `success` classes instead of always leaving both after the initial validation happens?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

Basically, if your CSS is not updated after adding your class valid that is the class rules are not overridden. Why? The problem is not on the javascript side but rather on your CSS. Your Valid class must be declared AFTER your Error class....

I spent 2 hours looking for the problem on JS but it's on CSS.... argh....

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly which plugin you're using. But I guess it should look something like this.

```
$("form").validate({
    success: 
        function(label) {

            if (label.attr('for') == "username") {
                var element = '#' + label.attr('for');
                label.removeClass("error").addClass("valid").text("Username available");
            } else {
                label.removeClass("error");
            }


    },
    error: 
        function(label) {

            if (label.attr('for') == "username") {
                var element = '#' + label.attr('for');
                label.addClass("error").removeClass("valid").text("Username unavailable");
            } else {
                label.addClass("error");
            }


    }
});

$("#regForm").validate();
```

Comment: I went ahead and tried your solution, however it does not work or have any effect on the behavior of the validate plugin, nor look like something I would have expected to work from what I have read in the documentation for the plugin. But thank you for attempting to help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't think you want to wait until the form is revalidated you should set a function to the field itself so when ever a user has changed the text you remove the username available message but if you are validating often enough you wouldn't have to worry about that.

You JavaScript looks fine but you need to make sure your HTML is set up correctly using jQuery text with a label that doesn't look something like the following can cause problems.

```
<label id="myLabel"></label>
```

There is a short note in the comments of the jQuery page [here](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: It is initially validating on loss of focus, and then re-validating on every keypress. Your solution didn't actually solve my problem directly, since the labels were correctly formatted, but when I started looking at the generated source code for the labels to see if they were formed correctly, that got me thinking to look in the plugin source code to see how those labels were generated, which brought a red-flag to my attention: the label is only re-used if it has the "error" class associated with it. Thank you for your assistance in finding a working solution, I have created working code now!