# jQuery validation success message not styled

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate, message

I am styling the messages in red for errors and green for success. But the messages appear to be in red for success.

Here is the validation code:

```
debug: true,
errorElement: "em",             
success: function(label) {
    label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
},
```

And here is the CSS code snippet:

```
em.success
{
    float: none; 
    color: green; 
    padding-left: .5em; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px;    
}

em.error 
{ 
    float: none; 
    color: red; 
    padding-left: .5em; 
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

What exactly is wrong in my code?

Please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K9b9R/7/).

Comment: Looking at the Fiddle, the OK message appears green when it's a valid input. It's only adding duplicate OKs... what's the behavior you want?

Comment: I would like only one OK message in green. Having duplicates should be eliminated.

Comment: So, refer to my updated answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the duplicate OK, do this:

```
success: function(label)
{
    label.text("").text("ok!").addClass("success");
}
```

Comment: Thats the one! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: It was not the text content that was duplicated, it was the error element itself. Removing the `removeClass` helps (as you did). You do not need the `.text("")` as `.empty()` is called internally before creating a text node.

Answer (score 1):

I think your label ends up with both classes `success` and `error`, so following [the rules to determine a CSS property value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order), the latter wins and your text is red (assumed the order of the CSS rules are the same as in your question).

As to why they have both: The [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) says that if `success` is specified, "the error label is displayed to show a valid element". I am not entirely sure what this means. You might want to dig into that (debug the label, check the element in Firebug or dev tools, look at the [source of the plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js)).

In your demo on jsfiddle.net the only problem seems to be the multiple success labels. I found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5955284/95033) stating that if you remove the "error" class, the labels are not cleared up. [I removed the `removeClass` from your example](http://jsfiddle.net/K9b9R/8/) and it seems to work as you would want it to (only one label, colors ok).

Comment: I changed the order in the CSS, but it dint make any change, the messages are still in red color.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: That certainly helps! Thank you!